# Assign value in column based on string in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1"],data=(["SUPER_280"],["AASD"],
["AASD"],["SUPER_350"],["AASD"],["SUPER_150"],["AASD"],["AASD"]))
```

which results in the following table

```
    col1
0   SUPER_280
1   AASD
2   AASD
3   SUPER_350
4   AASD
5   SUPER_150
6   AASD
7   AASD
```

Actual data is much longer.

I want to make a scrip that checks the string in col1 and if it finds the substring "SUPER" take the last three characters from the string and assigns them in a second column up to the next "SUPER".
I want to achieve this:

`````
    col1        col2
0   SUPER_280   280
1   AASD        280
2   AASD        280
3   SUPER_350   350
4   AASD        350
5   SUPER_150   150
6   AASD        150
7   AASD        150
​````

Thanks in advance
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check where the word `SUPER` appears, 
then keep the last 3 characters with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and fill in the rest with [Series.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].where(df1['col1'].str.contains('SUPER')).str[-3:].ffill()
```

We can also use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors = 'coerce'` 
to transform the last 3 characters to numerical and fill in the rest with [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
df1['col2']=pd.to_numeric(df1['col1'].str[-3:],errors='coerce').ffill()
```

**Output**

```
        col1   col2
0  SUPER_280  280.0
1       AASD  280.0
2       AASD  280.0
3  SUPER_350  350.0
4       AASD  350.0
5  SUPER_150  150.0
6       AASD  150.0
7       AASD  150.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str.split` + `Series.ffill`:

```
df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].str.split('_').str[1].ffill()
```

Or by using `np.where` to conditionally check if `col1` has `SUPER`:

```
mask = df1['col1'].str.contains('SUPER')
df1 = df1.assign(col2 = np.where(mask, df1['col1'].str[-3:], np.NaN)).ffill()
```

```
        col1 col2
0  SUPER_280  280
1       AASD  280
2       AASD  280
3  SUPER_350  350
4       AASD  350
5  SUPER_150  150
6       AASD  150
7       AASD  150
```

Answer (score 1):

Test value `SUPER` by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), get last 3 values of column by indexing and then forward filling missing values:

```
m = df1['col1'].str.contains('SUPER')

df1.loc[m, 'col2'] = df1.loc[m, 'col1'].str[-3:]
df1['col2'] = df1['col2'].ffill()
print (df1)
        col1 col2
0  SUPER_280  280
1       AASD  280
2       AASD  280
3  SUPER_350  350
4       AASD  350
5  SUPER_150  150
6       AASD  150
7       AASD  150
```

Answer (score 1):

It separates the expression according to the character `_`, takes the last element and assigns it to `col2` if it is `digit`, and assigns `None` to `col2`  if not. Then, fills with `ffill`according to the previous value.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1"],data=(["SUPER_280"],["AASD"],
>>> ... ["AASD"],["SUPER_350"],["AASD"],["SUPER_150"],["AASD"],["AASD"]))
>>> df1
        col1
0  SUPER_280
1       AASD
2       AASD
3  SUPER_350
4       AASD
5  SUPER_150
6       AASD
7       AASD
>>> df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1] if x.split('_')[-1].isdigit() else None).ffill()
>>> df1
        col1 col2
0  SUPER_280  280
1       AASD  280
2       AASD  280
3  SUPER_350  350
4       AASD  350
5  SUPER_150  150
6       AASD  150
```